# reading a certain part of a file with fseek

Tags: file, fseek

I have to read a png file(in binary) and i have to get out height and width of the picture(starting as 17 and long 8bytes together).

i tried

```
FILE* picture = fopen("test.png","rb");
fseek(picture, 16 , SEEK_SET);

int counter = 0;
while(counter < 8){
    fscanf(picture, "%d", temp[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should never read binary files using the file-library, but rather the system-calls `read` and `write`.

```
void* buf = malloc(1024);
memset(buf,0,1024);

int picturefd = open("test.png",O_RDONLY);
lseek(picturefd, 16 , SEEK_SET);

if(read(picturefd, buf, 8) < 8){
//failed to read or eof reached
}
```

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/read.htm) for `read` and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/lseek.htm) for `lseek`.